# withFilter instead of filter

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, scala-collections, for-comprehension

Is it always more performant to use withFilter instead of filter, when afterwards applying       functions like map, flatmap etc.?

Why are only map, flatmap and foreach supported? (Expected functions like forall/exists as well)

Comment: [This part of Scala doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) also has a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

From [the Scala docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#withFilter(p:A=>Boolean):scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic[A,Repr]):

> Note: the difference between `c filter p` and `c withFilter p` is that the former
>       creates a new collection, whereas the latter only restricts the domain of
>       subsequent `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, and `withFilter` operations.

So `filter` will take the original collection and produce a new collection, but `withFilter` will non-strictly (i.e. lazily) pass unfiltered values through to later `map`/`flatMap`/`withFilter` calls, saving a second pass through the (filtered) collection. Hence it will be more efficient when passing through to these subsequent method calls.

In fact, `withFilter` is specifically designed for working with chains of these methods, which is what a for comprehension is de-sugared into. No other methods (such as `forall`/`exists`) are required for this, so they have not been added to the `FilterMonadic` return type of `withFilter`.

Comment: Hope they still add these methods some day.

Comment: @Kigyo I don't think you're supposed to use withFilter yourself (apart from implicitly within for-expressions). Use `view` if you want maps / filters to be lazy.

Comment: I see. Whats the exact difference between `view` and `withFilter`? Why isn't view used for `for-loops`?

Comment: @Kigyo `view.filter` will behave identically to `withFilter` on types that provide `view` i.e. collections. But a view is rich interface and for comprehensions are used with many non-collection types e.g. Option, Future. `withFilter` is all that's needed for an efficient translation, so it makes sense to require only that in the contract.

Comment: Just for reference, I think that [Collections - Tips and Tricks](https://pavelfatin.com/scala-collections-tips-and-tricks/#sequences-rewriting) provides outstanding information. H5s aren't anchored, but you can search for `Don’t create temporary collections` in the linked section.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "...pass unfiltered values...". The values passed on are certainly *filtered*, are they not - just lazily passed through.

Comment: @nclark I just mean values that did not get filtered out, values that passed the filter criterion.

Comment: Regarding the explicit use of `withFilter`, Martin Odersky himself uses it explicitly in his Scala courses on Coursera, which I highly recommend. Given that he does so, it may give others comfort with doing so as well, although the difference is typically only 1 character. For example `seq.view filter p` vs. `seq withFilter p`.

Comment: @ChuckDaniels - Thanks. And further, the comment on withFilter as of Scala 2.11 doesn't say not to use it.

Answer (score 14):

In addition of [the excellent answer of Shadowlands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19617378/2780334), I would like to bring an intuitive example of the difference between `filter` and `withFilter`.

Let's consider the following code

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
var go = true
val result = for(i <- list; if(go)) yield {
   go = false
   i
}
```

Most people expect `result` to be equal to `List(1)`. This is the case since Scala 2.8, because the for-comprehension is translated into

```
val result = list withFilter {
  case i => go
} map {
  case i => {
    go = false
    i
  }
}
```

As you can see the translation converts the condition into a call to `withFilter`. Prior Scala 2.8, for-comprehension were translated into something like the following:

```
val r2 = list filter {
  case i => go
} map {
  case i => {
    go = false
    i
  }
}
```

Using `filter`, the value of `result` would be fairly different: `List(1, 2, 3)`. The fact that we're making the `go` flag `false` has no effect on the filter, because the filter is already done. Again, in Scala 2.8, this issue is solved using `withFilter`. When `withFilter` is used, the condition is evaluated every time an element is accessed inside a `map` method.

**Reference**:
  - p.120 ,Scala in action (covers Scala 2.10), Manning Publications, Milanjan Raychaudhuri
  - [Odersky's thoughts about for-comprehension translation](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3698.html#comment-14546)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason because *forall/exists* aren't implemented  is that the use case is that:

- you can lazily apply withFilter to an infinite stream/iterable
- you can lazily apply another withFilter  (and again and again)

To implement *forall/exists* we need to obtain all the elements, loosing the lazyness.

So for example:

```
import scala.collection.AbstractIterator

class RandomIntIterator extends AbstractIterator[Int] {
  val rand = new java.util.Random
  def next: Int = rand.nextInt()
  def hasNext: Boolean = true
}

//rand_integers  is an infinite random integers iterator
val rand_integers = new RandomIntIterator

val rand_naturals = 
    rand_integers.withFilter(_ > 0)

val rand_even_naturals = 
    rand_naturals.withFilter(_ % 2 == 0)

println(rand_even_naturals.map(identity).take(10).toList)

//calling a second time we get
//another ten-tuple of random even naturals
println(rand_even_naturals.map(identity).take(10).toList)
```

Note that *ten_rand_even_naturals* is still an iterator. **Only** when we call *toList* the random numbers will be generated and filtered in chain

Note that *map(identity)* is equivalent to *map(i=>i)* and it is used here in order to convert a withFilter object back to the original type (eg a collection , a stream, an iterator)

Answer (score 1):

For the forall/exists part:

```
someList.filter(conditionA).forall(conditionB)
```

would be the same as (though a little bit un-intuitive)

```
!someList.exists(conditionA && !conditionB)
```

Similarly, .filter().exists() can be combined into one exists() check?

Answer (score -3):

Using for yield can be a work around, for example:

```
for {
  e <- col;
  if e isNotEmpty
} yield e.get(0)
```

Answer (score -5):

As a workaround, you can implement other functions with only `map` and `flatMap`.

Moreover, this optimisation is useless on small collections…