# Scala: Get specific elements by a sequence of indices

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I get specific elements of an array by having the sequence of indices, I do it now by following:

```
val indices = Array(1,3,3,2)
val a = Array("a","b","c","d","e","f")
indices.map(a(_))
```

the problem is if I want to make it a safe search I have to check a.contains or modify the indices. sometimes the indices is to big and I can not modify it fast. What is the best time/space solution?

Comment: I think you can just do `indices.map(a)`

Answer (score 6):

Here it is:

```
scala> val indices = Array(1, 2, 3, 2, 100, -100, 4, 5)
indices: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 2, 100, -100, 4, 5)

scala> val arr = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
arr: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)

scala> indices collect arr
res1: Array[String] = Array(b, c, d, c)
```

Comment: Do you know how is the complexity of collect?

Comment: @Omid `collect` traverses the collection exactly once.

Comment: By the way, what would `indices collect arr` look like desugared?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to ignore every out-of-bounds-index you could just use a filter before mapping:

```
indices.filter(_ < a.length).map(a(_))
```

Comment: the first filter needs go over all data, it takes 2*size of indices time and size

Comment: Change `filter` to `withFilter` and you remove the `2n` iteration time at the least (not sure about the space off the top of my head though).

Comment: @SeanVieira  What is the difference between them ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19618241/135978 - basically, withFilter is most likely lazy and doesn't create another collection - instead it's a simplified `view`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flatMap` where out of bound indexes are mapped onto `None`, like this,

```
indices.flatMap(i => if (i < a.length) Some(a(i)) else None)
```

Simpler forms with `flatMap`,

```
indices.flatMap(i => Some(a(i)))
res: Array(b, d, d, c)

indices.flatMap(a(_))
res: Array(b, d, d, c)
```

Comment: Why? This is like collect only less clear. If you really don't want to use collect, then foldLeft would probably be quicker

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use collect you may try :

```
val indices = Array(1, 2, 3, 2)
val arr = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
val res = for (i <- indices) yield arr(i)
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't address safety, as mentioned in the question.