# Scala: Implementing map and withFilter in a simple custom type

Tags: scala, for-loop, monads

I'm learning Scala and already had to find out that the concept of monads is a bit too sophisticated for my current level of knowledge. However, my goal is at least to make a very simple class that can be used with the `for` expression and additionally a filter.

From my point of understanding, the following rules apply:

- In order for a custom type to be usable in the generator of a for expression (where the generator only produces simple variables), it needs to implement `map`.
- If filters should be used in addition, then the type also has to implement `withFilter`.

My minimal classes look like this:

```
class Grid(private val fields: IndexedSeq[Field])

class Field(val name: String, val isVisible: Boolean)
```

What I want to achieve is be able to do the following:

```
for(f <- grid) yield f.name // needs map
for(f <- grid; if f.isVisisble) yield f.name // needs map + withFilter
```

However, I have a hard time finding examples with that kind of simplicity. It's ok if the solution is "tailored" to the two classes shown above instead of being a general solution that can be applied to any classes. Unterstanding the implementation for this simple example would definitely help me. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**Edit:**

As Lee pointed out, my intention only seem to work for generic types. I assume it would make more sense if I forget about the class `Field` and redefine `Grid` as follows:

```
class Grid[E](private val fields: IndexedSeq[E])
```

Comment: `map` and `withFilter` only make sense for generic types, which `Grid` and `Field` are not. How would `for(f <- grid) yield f.name` work for example?

Comment: @Lee Thanks for your response, have to think about it. Does my edit change anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you can just pass the `map` call on to the wrapped collection `fields`.
For `withFilter` you can call the `filter` method on `fields`, but I think that's not entirely in line with the semantics that `withFilter` is supposed to have.

```
case class Grid[E](private val fields: IndexedSeq[E]) {
  def map[R](f: E => R): Grid[R] = new Grid(fields map f)
  def withFilter(p: E => Boolean): Grid[E] = new Grid(fields filter p)
}
```

A more correct, but convoluted implementation of what you are asking would be:

```
case class Grid[E](private val fields: IndexedSeq[E]) {
  def map[R](f: E => R): Grid[R] = new Grid(fields map f)
  def withFilter(p: E => Boolean): WithFilter = new WithFilter(p)

  class WithFilter(p: E => Boolean) {
    def map[R](f: E => R): Grid[R] = new Grid(fields.withFilter(p).map(f))
    def withFilter(q: E => Boolean): WithFilter = new WithFilter(x => p(x) && q(x))
  }
}
```

That way, `withFilter` will work [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617378/withfilter-instead-of-filter) as expected.

Comment: I needed to implement `flatMap` on `WithFilter` also (`def flatMap[R](f: E => Grid[R]): Grid[R]`)

Answer (score 2):

It will work with even not generic definition of `Grid`, yet `map` isn't what you expect:

```
case class Field(name: String, isVisible: Boolean)

case class Grid(val fields: IndexedSeq[Field]) {
  def map[B](f: Field => B): IndexedSeq[B] =
    fields.map(f)

   def filter(f: Field => Boolean): Grid =
     new Grid(fields.filter(f))
}

val grid = new Grid(Vector(Field("foo", true), Field("bar", false)))

// works
for { f <- grid } yield f.name
// res7: IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(foo, bar)

for { f <- grid; if f.isVisible } yield f.name
// res13: IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(foo)
```

For-comprehension de-sugaring is syntax-based. It rewrites the expression using `.map` `.flatMap` `.filter` etc and then type-checks (AFAIK).