# Performance comparison between map and for in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, jvm

I wanted to know when both of them are doing the same thing, what can be possible use cases to use the first one over the second statement.

```
    val xs = List[Int](1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

for a list of numbers :

```
    for (x <- xs if x%2 == 0) 
           yield x*10
```

same as :

```
    xs.filter(_%2 == 0).map(_*10)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is no performance difference. The code using the `for` loop under the hood will be translated into the code with `filter` and `map` (the details can varied depending on Scala version). It is matter of your preferences which version you want to use. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/460363) for more details.

Comment: Thanks :) What you think would happen if the operation is being performed on a spark RDD ?  ( I mean , if xs is a RDD ? )

Comment: Translation of for loop into the code with map/for is performed by a compiler. It means that it should work in the same way regardless of what kind of collection is used.

Comment: makes sense :) Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK for comprehension would use `withFilter` instead of `filter` when desugared which avoids intermediate collection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617378/withfilter-instead-of-filter