# Scala Stream vs Java Stream Laziness Difference

Tags: java, scala, java-8, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to the concept of lazy evaluation. When I execute this line of code in Scala;

```
"12334".grouped(1).toStream.filter{n => println("n:" +n ); n=="3";}
```

It prints out:

```
n:1
n:2
n:3
```

But when I run something similar in Java, like:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("12334".split("")));

Stream<String> myList2 = myList.stream().filter(a -> {System.out.println("a:" +a);return "3".equals(a);});
```

It terminates silently without writing anything to console line. Java's behavior seems more reasonable to me because Streams are lazily evaluated and
I did not collect or try to print result. But in Scala even if I did not consume stream it prints out some information. So my question is what is causing that difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's due to the fact that `filter` isn't entirely lazy. It has this piece of code:

```
while (!rest.isEmpty && !p(rest.head)) rest = rest.tail
```

Which causes materialization and actual filtering of the `Stream`.

If you want full laziness, go with `withFilter`:

```
"12334".grouped(1).toStream.withFilter { n => println("n:" +n ); n=="3"; }
```

For more see [withFilter instead of filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617378/withfilter-instead-of-filter).