# Collection view vs withFilter

Tags: scala

Both views and withFilter solve the problem of intermediate collection creations. What's the difference between them ?

```
List("a", "b", "c").withFilter(_ == "b").withFilter(_ == "c").map(x => x)
```

vs

```
 List("a", "b", "c").view.filter(_ == "b").filter(_ == "c").map(x => x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List("a", "b", "c").withFilter(_ == "b").withFilter(_ == "c").map(x => x)
```

Result:

```
 List[String] = List()
```

Note: the result is no longer lazy.

```
List("a", "b", "c").view.filter(_ == "b").filter(_ == "c").map(x => x)
```

Result:

```
scala.collection.SeqView[String,Seq[_]] = SeqViewFFM(...)
```

The result has not been evaluated, it is still a view.

Answer (score 2):

The first is lazy until you call the `map`, while the second one is just lazy (not executed). For the second one it will finally execute when decide to call `force` - which you have not done in your example. So it'd look like:

`List("a", "b", "c").view.filter(_ == "b").filter(_ == "c").map(x => x).force`

this is equivalent to the first one.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618241/6610934) and [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) about `withFilter` and `view` in Scala.