# How to pair each element of a Seq with the rest?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm looking for an elegant way to combine every element of a `Seq` with the rest for a large collection.
Example: `Seq(1,2,3).someMethod` should produce something like

```
Iterator(
  (1,Seq(2,3)),
  (2,Seq(1,3)),
  (3,Seq(1,2))
)
```

Order of elements doesn't matter. It doesn't have to be a tuple, a `Seq(Seq(1),Seq(2,3))` is also acceptable (although kinda ugly).

Note the emphasis on *large* collection (which is why my example shows an `Iterator`).
Also note that this is not `combinations`.

Ideas?

**Edit:**
In my use case, the numbers are expected to be unique. If a solution can eliminate the dupes, that's fine, but not at additional cost. Otherwise, dupes are acceptable.

**Edit 2:** In the end, I went with a nested `for`-loop, and skipped the case when `i == j`. No new collections were created. I upvoted the solutions that were correct and simple (*"simplicity is the ultimate sophistication"* - Leonardo da Vinci), but even the best ones are quadratic just by the nature of the problem, and some create intermediate collections by usage of `++` that I wanted to avoid because the collection I'm dealing with has close to 50000 elements, 2.5 billion when quadratic.

Comment: What if there are duplicates in your original sequence, says, Seq(1, 1, 1), would the output be 3x `1 -> Seq(1, 1)`, or do you wish to de-dup?

Answer (score 3):

The following code has constant runtime (it does everything lazily), but accessing every element of the resulting collections has constant overhead (when accessing each element, an index shift must be computed every time):

```
def faceMap(i: Int)(j: Int) = if (j < i) j else j + 1

def facets[A](simplex: Vector[A]): Seq[(A, Seq[A])] = {
  val n = simplex.size
  (0 until n).view.map { i => (
    simplex(i),
    (0 until n - 1).view.map(j => simplex(faceMap(i)(j)))
  )}
}
```

Example:

```
println("Example: facets of a 3-dimensional simplex")
for ((i, v) <- facets((0 to 3).toVector)) {
  println(i + " -> " + v.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
}
```

Output:

```
Example: facets of a 3-dimensional simplex
0 -> [1,2,3]
1 -> [0,2,3]
2 -> [0,1,3]
3 -> [0,1,2]
```

This code expresses everything in terms of [simplices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_category), because "omitting one index" corresponds exactly to the [face maps](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category#Definition) for a combinatorially described simplex. To further illustrate the idea, here is what the `faceMap` does:

```
println("Example: how `faceMap(3)` shifts indices")
for (i <- 0 to 5) {
  println(i + " -> " + faceMap(3)(i))
}
```

gives:

```
Example: how `faceMap(3)` shifts indices
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 4
4 -> 5
5 -> 6
```

The `facets` method uses the `faceMap`s to create a lazy view of the original collection that omits one element by shifting the indices by one starting from the index of the omitted element.

Comment: Clever. But in the end of the day, getting all the results materialized, is still quadratic, right? So, essentially, the same as what I have (perhaps, with `.view` added before `.filter`) ...

Comment: @Dima If you force every view into an explicit linear data structure (e.g. array or list), then the resulting data structures will occupy *quadratic space*, so, if you force all the views, you will also have quadratic runtime. But maybe forcing every view is not necessary, maybe it's sufficient to leave the original vector with the data at the same position in memory, and then address the elements with the funny index-shifts described above. In this case, it only adds constant overhead for each element access, and uses almost no extra space.

Comment: ... or if you iterate over each element of every view. It may still be linear (constant?)  space, but quadratic time.

Comment: @Dima yeah, right... Iterating over each element of the resulting views would also be `O(n^2)` time. The lazy views merely give you the opportunity to pay only for what you actually use - if you don't use it, it's not materialized.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want correctly, in terms of handling duplicate values (i.e., duplicate values are to be preserved), here's something that should work. Given the following input:

```
import scala.util.Random

val nums = Vector.fill(20)(Random.nextInt)
```

This should get you what you need:

```
for (i <- Iterator.from(0).take(nums.size)) yield {
  nums(i) -> (nums.take(i) ++ nums.drop(i + 1))
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to remove dups, I'd convert to Sets:

```
val numsSet = nums.toSet
for (num <- nums) yield {
  num -> (numsSet - num)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
seq.iterator.map { case x => x -> seq.filter(_ != x) }
```

This is quadratic, but I don't think there is very much you can do about that, because in the end of the day, creating a collection is linear, and you are going to need `N` of them.

Comment: `filterNot` is going to create a copy for even non-strict sequences, isn't it? Perhaps `withFilter` is better.

Comment: Interesting ... I didn't know that. No idea, why it does that actually, looks like a bug. 
`filter` does the right thing. Weird.  I'll update.

Comment: `filter` has the same behavior, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618241/839733) post.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't. I just checked it in repl.

Comment: What doesn't? `filter` doesn't create new collection, or `filterNot` doesn't?

Comment: They both create a new collection. But if the original collection is lazy, then result of `.filter` is also lazy (while the result of `.filterNot` is for some reason strict).

Comment: If the sequence has more than one X, your implementation removes all of them. I don't believe this is what the question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def prems(s : Seq[Int]):Map[Int,Seq[Int]]={
  @tailrec
  def p(prev: Seq[Int],s :Seq[Int],res:Map[Int,Seq[Int]]):Map[Int,Seq[Int]] = s match {
    case x::Nil => res+(x->prev)
    case x::xs=> p(x +: prev,xs, res+(x ->(prev++xs)))
  }

  p(Seq.empty[Int],s,Map.empty[Int,Seq[Int]])
}

prems(Seq(1,2,3,4))
res0: Map[Int,Seq[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(2, 3, 4), 2 -> List(1, 3, 4), 3 -> List(2, 1, 4),4 -> List(3, 2, 1))
```

Comment: Seems too complicated

Comment: it's a simple recursion (essentially a reduce) that builds the previous items which it always concatenate to the tail (rest of the sequence) as it traverser the sequence once

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for [`permutations`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#permutations:Iterator[Repr]). You can map the resulting lists into the structure you are looking for:

```
Seq(1,2,3).permutations.map(p => (p.head, p.tail)).toList
res49: List[(Int, Seq[Int])] = List((1,List(2, 3)), (1,List(3, 2)), (2,List(1, 3)), (2,List(3, 1)), (3,List(1, 2)), (3,List(2, 1)))
```

Note that the final `toList` call is only there to trigger the evaluation of the expressions; otherwise, the result is an iterator as you asked for.

In order to get rid of the duplicate heads, `toMap` seems like the most straight-forward approach:

```
Seq(1,2,3).permutations.map(p => (p.head, p.tail)).toMap
res50: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(3, 2), 2 -> List(3, 1), 3 -> List(2, 1))
```

Comment: This is going to create a bunch of intermediate collections. Perhaps that's why someone (not me) downvoted you.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar "bunch of" is a little bit vague. It will generate a superexponential amount of irrelevant duplicates for a problem where even the completely materialized explicit solution is of quadratic size (factorial grows faster than exponential function).

Comment: I agree that there are many redundant pairs are created, but I doubt that this is harmful memory-wise. The intermediate collections are only actually evaluated in the `toMap` step; `Seq(1,2,3).permutations.map(p => (p.head, p.tail))` results in an `Iterator`. I am pretty sure `toMap` is _not_ implemented in a way that it stores all intermediate pairs in memory. Runtime complexity is another issue, obviously.